# Laravel - how to get list of migrations to do?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration

I have a long list of migration files and don't want to compare what already ran and what is suppopsed to run next time when I do 
`php artisan migrate`
Is there a way how to display such list ( without actually installing new 3rd party package)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Better user `php artisan migrate:status`

This will basically show you the migrations which have been run and which are pending as well

Comment: That's something I can easily live with. 
`php artisan migrate:status | grep "| No   |"` gives me what I was looking for without need of creating custom script.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `php artisan migrate --pretend` to dump a list of all database queries that would be ran if you would migrate. But there is no command to list the migration files that would be executed.

Comment: Great thank you, so DIY shell script will do that for me